# What is best practices in Prolog when assigning a number to a variable?

Tags: prolog

To illustrate the difference between 'is' and '=', next example is given in my Prolog course:

```
?- X is 2+3
X = 5.

?- X = 2+3.
X = 2+3.
```

However, both `Y is 3` and `Y = 3` seem to do the same. Is there a difference? And if not, is there a convention not to use one of the two in Prolog programs?

Comment: `is` is assignment. `=` is unification of each side of the `=`. It is not assignment. So the correct answer for assignment is `is`. You can see in your results that they are different. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Prolog, `=/2` and `is/2` serve very different purposes. `is/2` is used to assign a value from an arithmetic expression. The right hand side must be fully instantiated (all variables bound) and it will compute the expression and unify it with the single variable on the left. For example:

```
Y = 3,
X is log(Y+7)/2.

X = 1.151292546497023
Y = 3
```

The `=` is used to unify terms on each side of the `=`. So when you say:

```
X = log(Y+7)/2.
```

That is unifying the term `X` with the term `log(Y+7)/2` (or, technically, `'/'(log('+'(Y,7),2)`) which gives you `X = log(Y+7)/2`. It doesn't compute `log(Y+7)/2.` because that's not the job of `=`. That's a job for `is/2`.

With `=` you can also say things like:

```
foo(X, _) = foo(3, blah).
```

And you will get `X = 3` since it can unify both terms by setting `X` to `3`.

In the simplest case, these operators appear to be the same because `X is 3` evaluates the expression `3` and assigns it (binds it to) `X`, and `X = 3` unifies `X` with `3`. Both results are the same in this case.